# How to Encrypt and Decrypt the data and how to send in Querystring url

Tags: asp.net, encryption, query-string

I have a web application in that in have two forms in this i have pass the Encrypted data with the Querystring.In second page i get the Querystring data and then i need to Decrypt the data & bind that data in my page ...  for this i have write the code in this Encrypt and Decrypt is working in one(same aspx) page ,but when i redirect the  page Decrypt is throwing Error like

```
             Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
```

What can i do to resolve this Error Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64-bit encoding does not work well with spaces in the string

Add the following: `stringToDecrypt = stringToDecrypt.Replace(" ","+");`

Plus sign will be interpreted as a space when u call the FromBase64String method

Answer (score 0):

the only reason behind this is that you are not passing a right value in the querystring on the page where you are decrypting the querystring(either value has been changed explicitly or no use of **HttpUtility.UrlEncode()** while encrypting).

and also make sure that you are using **HttpUtility.UrlDecode** while decrypting.